# Searching for the right temperature sensor with 0.001

Tags: sensor, temperature

Is it possible for me to build a temperature sensor with 1mK accuracy?

First I think I need to find the right temperature sensor. My problem right now is I can't find a temperature sensor with that accuracy.

Thanks for the help.

**Edit 1**: As I can read from the comments finding the right sensor might not be a problem but the calibration will be a problem. I will discuss with my supervisor whether he can reduce the accuracy requirements or not. Thanks for your responses.

**Edit 2**: The application of the sensor is for measuring the accurate freezing point of milk to be use in a milk quality tester.

Comment: You really mean accuracy and not resolution? What kind of application has these requirements if I may ask?

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic in this forum.  Reference: Help->Tour->Don't ask about...Shopping or buying recommendations.

Comment: I'm sure you can solve this problem for only money...probably large amounts of money. What's the requirement driving this kind of accuracy requirement? It seems a bit ridiculous.

Comment: As a chemist, I'm confused. Milk will not freeze over a 1mK range. The clear component is an aqueous solution, whose freezing point depends on its concentration. As it begins to freeze pure ice will crystallize out, which will cause the concentration of the remaining liquid to increase, so that "complete" freezing will occur over an ill-defined range. Additionally milk is not a simple solution (if it was it would be transparent) but in fact contains suspended colloidal particles (making it opaque) which means its behaviour will be quite complex.

Answer (score 6):

1mK resolution is not such a big deal, and 1mK accuracy is not such a big deal for the electronics, at least over a narrow range (just expensive- a 0.03% reference resistor with a minimal tempco).

The problem is calibration. Other than the triple point of water, which is a (relatively) easy source of 0.01°C +/-0.1mK it's expensive and difficult to calibrate the sensor to such tolerances.

Construction of such sensors is typically a loose coil of very pure platinum wire inside a quartz tube (sort of looks like a small version of an aquarium heater). Film type sensors have too much hysteresis. Called an SPRT (Standard Platinum Resistance Thermometer). Very slow response time and each unit will come with a calibration table for that particular sensor (perhaps suitable for framing) and an enormous invoice. It would likely have to be recalibrated at least annually.

You could buy the equipment and do it yourself, but it seems a bit involved:

[image]

You might want to read the [NIST document](http://www.nist.gov/calibrations/upload/sp250-81.pdf) that was the source of the above photo to see what's involved.

Edit: Since the application is measuring the freezing point of milk, not (say) molten aluminum, we need only full accuracy over a very narrow temperature range- from 0°C to -0.25°C probably (but discovering that is your job). So it is entirely practical to use the triple point of water as a single calibration point at +0.01°C and you only need a range of about 250mK. So you're only looking at 0.4% of span accuracy. This should be relatively straightforward, and can be accomplished with a PRT and a calibration cell.

Answer (score 4):

NPL quote this about PRT sensors: -

> Platinum resistance thermometers are electrical thermometers which
>   make use of the variation of resistance of high-purity platinum wire
>   with temperature. This variation is predictable, enabling accurate
>   measurements to be performed. They are sensitive and, with
>   sophisticated equipment, measurements, can routinely be made to better
>   than a thousandth part of 1°C.

Sounds good doesn't it? Read on...

[Here](http://www.npl.co.uk/educate-explore/factsheets/temperature/) is their page entitled "history of thermometry". It covers a fairly broad range of the devices available and PRTs are likely to be your best choice for accuracy BUT, the biggest problem is providing a stable reference.

You have to measure against "something" and that "something" is usually a voltage reference. The best voltage reference I can find (LTC6655) is 2ppm/deg C stable with an initial accuracy of 0.025%.

Local temperature changes will affect the voltage reference point - a 10 degree change in ambient moves the reference from 2.5 V to 2.50005 V. If full scale represents 100 deg C and 0V represents 0 deg C then 0.00005 volts error represents 5 milli deg C and your idea is busted.

This is why NPL mention the use of "sophisticated equipment" i.e. such things as temeperature controlled voltage references and, by inference, the very best ADCs you can get your hands on.

Another voltage reference by Maxim (MAX6126_30) has an initial accuracy of 0.02% - it's a 3V reference and 0.02% represents an error of 0.6 mV - if 3V represents 100 deg C and 0V is zero then 0.6 mV is equivalent to 60 milli deg C. Miles off what you need.

Answer (score 3):

you will struggle as most professional calibration units have 4 mk in the unit of error, then 4mk of error in wire sensing thermocouples, root Sum of the squares you have 6mk of system error(at least), thats thousands of dollars worth of delicate calibrated equipment
, that would be a pro system to calibrate your system! not really achievable ..... 10 mK maybe,  but all down to what range of temperature you are measuring,,,,(0-100 degC? -200 degC) direct you to what may achieve you goal,,

Comment: I am measuring the milk in room temperature so at most the sensor will be -5 °C to 50°C /60 °C. I also think that 10 mK will be enough for accuracy but the project description was 1mK . I will research about the accuracy. Thanks for the answer.